# Subprocesses don't run in parrallel - Multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I tried a lot of ways to call my subprocesses to run them in the same time. It creates all the processes but run only one at a time.

My 3 processes communicate with my main thanks to sockets (multiprocessing.connection.Listener / Client). The different processes each read different files, so there should be no I/O hassles.

Here you have everything that i tried :

1.

```
pool = Pool(cpu_count())
j = 0
while j < procs:
    pool.apply_async(run, args=())
    sleep(0.2)
    j += 1
pool.close()
```

2. 

```
j = 0
while j < procs:
    processes.append(Process(target=run, args=()))
    processes[-1].start()
    sleep(0.2)
    j += 1
```

3. 

```
pool = Pool(cpu_count())
j = 0
while j < procs:
    pool.apply(run, args=())
    sleep(0.2)
    j += 1
pool.close()
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> pool = Pool(cpu_count())
> ```

Useless, that's the default behaviour

> ```
> pool.apply_async(run, args=())
> sleep(0.2)
> ```

This submits *one* task, since you're sleeping afterwards unless the task takes more than 200ms (which is unlikely, 200ms is *a lot*) all the submissions will be sequential

> ```
> processes.append(Process(target=run, args=()))
> processes[-1].start()
> sleep(0.2)
> ```

Same as above, except possibly worse (it's not clear what the blocking behaviour of `start()` is).

> ```
> pool.apply(run, args=())
> sleep(0.2)
> ```

`apply` is blocking, so this will submit one job to the queue *and wait until that job is done*.

Only the first version would have any chance of leveraging the pool, and since you're sleeping for 200ms after the submission the job needs to take at least 200ms to be parallelised.

At no point are you explaining what `run` does, the only thing you say is that they're reading files, but even entry-level SSDs have GB/s-scale bandwidth, so you'd need to read in hundreds-MBs files at least for that effect to be sensible (possibly less if you're using very inefficient methods of reading).

The correct way to use a process pool is to either `apply_async` in a tight loop, or use `map_async` or `imap_unordered` to send in batches of jobs into the pool and let the pool distribute the work between the workers.

Also

> The different processes each read different files

There's certainly no indication or evidence of that, as they're all running the same `run` function with no parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The Run script will simply read certain files and search for a string of characters in these different files. Once done, it will send the various information collected to the main script. I am sure that the processes do not read the same files because it is the main script which will inform them later which ones they can read or not. In addition, I have already had the opportunity to debug this to verify that there is no error.
I apologize for my mistakes, I try to understand and learn that's why I ask questions.

Comment: Small clarification: I know that they are not running at the same time because they are all supposed to send a message to the server after having created a server thread themselves.